# Generating a new column in Spark SQL or MySQL based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
name varchar(20), 
dep varchar(20));

INSERT INTO temp VALUES 
('a', null), 
('b', null), 
('c', 'b'), 
('d', 'c'), 
('e', 'b'), 
('e', 'd');
```

I need the community help in writing a query that generates a new column, let's say **xyz**, which will have value 1 if **dep** is null. Else it has to take **dep** for the corresponding **name** and add 1 to **xyz** column value.

*For example: Here **c** is dependent on **b**, so it has to take the **xyz** of **b** which is having 1 and add 1 to it which gives **xyz** value of **c** as 2 and so on.*

output:

```
+------+------+-----+
| name |  dep | xyz |
+------+------+-----+
|  a   | null |  1  |
|  b   | null |  1  |
|  c   |  b   |  2  |
|  d   |  c   |  3  |
|  e   |  b   |  2  |
|  e   |  d   |  4  |
+------+------+-----+
```

Table creation:

```sql
create table temp1(name varchar(20), dependency varchar(20));
insert into temp1 values
    ('city', null), ('state', null), ('country', 'city'),
    ('country','state'), ('pin','country'), ('pin','state'),
    ('continent','country'), ('continent','pin'), ('continent','city');
```

Expected output: Here sequence is the new column to be generated.

```py
| name     | dependency | sequence |
|----------|------------|----------|
| city     | null       | 1        |
| state    | null       | 1        |
| country  | city       | 2        |
| country  | state      | 2        |
| pin      | country    | 3        |
| pin      | state      | 2        |
| continent| country    | 3        |
| continent| pin        | 4        |
| continent| city       | 2        |
```

My First question to the community :)
Thank U folks in advance.

Comment: Yep. Start with a tough one! Which db and version do you want to do this in?

Comment: Do you need a `pyspark̀` solution ? because there's the tag but you don't mention anything about spark in your question

Comment: You need a recursive query, MySql 8.0 has it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: I need spark SQL or pyspark or MySQL. I have updated the question with one more example. Help me with this folks.

Comment: The answer is updated, given your edit

Comment: Please help with recursive query. @all

Answer (score 1):

Try this, look at [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) here in `My SQL 8.0`

```
select
  name,
  dep,
  dense_rank() over (order by dep) as xyz
from myTable
order by
  name, dep
```

Output:

```
+--------------+
name  dep   xyz
+--------------+
 a  (null)   1
 b  (null)   1
 c    b      2
 d    c      3
 e    b      2
 e    d      4
```

For your second question, you can achieve it by simple `case` statement as following

```
select
    name,
    type,
    case
    when 
        (name = 'country' and type = 'city') 
        OR (name = 'continent' and type = 'city')
        OR (name = 'pin' and type = 'state')
        OR (name = 'country' and type = 'state') 
    then
        2
    when
        (name = 'pin' and type = 'country')
        OR (name = 'continent' and type = 'country')
    then
        3
    when
        (name = 'continent' and type = 'pin')
    then
        4
    else
        1
    end as ranks
from myTable
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------+
name        type      ranks
+--------------------------+
city        null        1
state       null        1
country     city        2
country     state       2
pin         country     3
pin         state       2
continent   country     3
continent   pin         4
continent   city        2
```

Comment: Thanks zealous . But I have added a new table to the question for which your query is not working as expected. Can you please help?

Comment: @zealous-- query has to be dynamic in nature. If there are 100s of records. How long the query will be with case statements :(

Answer (score 1):

@zealous answer seems to do the trick.

I can propose you the equivalent `pyspark` syntax (since `pyspark` is among the tags)

First, creating your dataframe

```py
import pyspark.sql.window as psw
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

​df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",None , 1), ("b", None ,1),
                            ("c","b",2), ("d","c",3),
                            ("e","b",2),("e","d",4)],
                           ['name','dep','xyz'])

df.show(5)

+----+----+---+
|name| dep|xyz|
+----+----+---+
|   a|null|  1|
|   b|null|  1|
|   c|   b|  2|
|   d|   c|  3|
|   e|   b|  2|
+----+----+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The idea is to order by `dep`: `Null` values are first and then you get an ordering of the letters. With `psf.dense_rank`, you don't have gaps in your ordering. To apply `dense_rank` in `Spark`, you need a `Window` function:

```py
w = psw.Window.orderBy('dep')
df.withColumn("xyz", psf.dense_rank().over(w))
​
df.show(5)
+----+----+---+
|name| dep|xyz|
+----+----+---+
|   a|null|  1|
|   b|null|  1|
|   c|   b|  2|
|   d|   c|  3|
|   e|   b|  2|
+----+----+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

## Update

For your second question, I don't seen any pattern that allows an elegant solution. You will need a series of `psf.when` statements.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df = spark.createDataFrame([('city', None),('state', None),
                            ('country', 'city'),('country','state'),
                            ('pin','country'),('pin','state'),
                            ('continent','country'),('continent','pin'),
                            ('continent','city')], ['name','type'])

df = df.withColumn("sequence", psf.when(
        ((psf.col('name') == "country" ) & (psf.col('type') == "city")) |
        ((psf.col('name') == "continent") & (psf.col('type') == "city")) |
        ((psf.col('name') == "pin") & (psf.col('type') == "state")) |
        ((psf.col('name') == "country") & (psf.col('type') == "state")),
        2
    ).when(
        ((psf.col('name') == "pin") & (psf.col('type') == "country")) |
        ((psf.col('name') == "continent") & (psf.col('type') == "country"))
  ,
        3
    ).when(
        (psf.col('name') == "continent") & (psf.col('type') == "pin"),
        4        
    ).otherwise(1)
    )

df.show(10)

+---------+-------+--------+
|     name|   type|sequence|
+---------+-------+--------+
|     city|   null|       1|
|    state|   null|       1|
|  country|   city|       2|
|  country|  state|       2|
|      pin|country|       3|
|      pin|  state|       2|
|continent|country|       3|
|continent|    pin|       4|
|continent|   city|       2|
+---------+-------+--------+
```

## To avoid `psf.when`

Since there is no obvious pattern in your conditions, I don't see other ways to do than using chained `when` or a `join`, that I now propose

The idea is to create a dataframe giving condition on your two columns and then merge it. Solution is untested.

```py
conditions = spark.createDataFrame([('country', 'city',2),('continent','city',2),
                            ('pin','state',2),('country','state',2),
                            ('pin','country',3),('continent','country',3),
                            ('continent','pin', 4)],
['name','type','sequence'])

df = df.join(psf.broadcast(conditions),
             ['name', 'type'], 'left_outer')
       .fillna(1, subset=['sequence'])
```

By the way, I use `psf.broadcast` to speed up the merge because the `conditions` `DataFrame` should be of reasonable size.

If you have a large number of conditions, I think this approach should be preferred. It will make your code more readable

Comment: @linog-: I have updated my question. Can you please help me with that?? Thank U

Comment: The answer has been updated. There are no elegant way to do that except by using a series of `when` statements as @zealous proposed

Comment: Thanku U linog. But query will keep on increasing with number of records. Please help me with python or pyspark loop kind of solution. I think that helps.

Comment: I updated. I don't know how to do that with loop but I propose you a solution based on `join`. If the answer satisfies you, you can accept it